# How to make SAFEARRAYs threadsafe if locking is unsafe?

Tags: c++, vb.net, multithreading, vba, safearray

I'm writing a C++ DLL that takes SAFEARRAYs passed in from Excel VBA. The DLL has multiple threads sharing the SAFEARRAYs (both reading from and writing to them). While trying to figure out how to do the sharing safely, I came across [this bit of MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221492(v=vs.85).aspx):

> For example, consider an application that uses the SafeArrayLock and SafeArrayUnlock functions. If these functions are called concurrently from different threads on the same SAFEARRAY data type instance, an inconsistent lock count may be created. This will eventually cause the SafeArrayUnlock function to return E_UNEXPECTED. You can prevent this by providing your own synchronization code.

It's confusing me because I thought the whole point of locks was to ensure thread safety and clearly this locking functionality is not intended for that. But why would you need locking in a single-threaded application?

The documentation for SafeArrayLock also says that the function "places a pointer to the array data in pvData of the array descriptor" but by my tests, the pvData pointer is valid even when SafeArrayLock has never been called (and the lock count is 0). For example, this function:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall testfun(VARIANT& vararr) {
    if (vararr.parray->cLocks != 0) throw -1; 
    else {
        double* data = (double*) vararr.parray->pvData;
        data[5] = 4.1;
    }
}
```

effectively writes to the array stored in vararr and the change is visible in the VBA that calls it. What's up with that?

Given the seeming persistence of pvData and the unsafe locking mechanism, my instinct is to just scrap all the array manipulation functions and let my threads reach into pvData as they please (the writes never collide, so what could go wrong?) but others on here caution against manual array manipulation for unclear reasons. What's the right approach? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hoping that the pointer remains consistent when used in a way other than the documented one is perhaps a risky idea; that way madness and undefined behaviour lies. Remember also that (a) "lock" has multiple meaning in software development and (b) `SAFEARRAY` might be sufficiently old that the original devs didn't care about thread safety because no-one would be using it on a multicore/processor system.